# What is the proper way to make the find_monthly_savings function return the amount divided by the months in a year (in twelve months) in Python

Tags: python, function

So my issue is I've been working on solving a problem to learn Python (it say it's for beginners and I've worked through it however I struggle with the return function for some reason and calculations).

I need to make the `find_monthly_savings` function take the amount & years functions to calculate the amount the user needs to save "each month" and if the `amount is < 0` then `return None` or if the `years <= 0` then `return None`.

```
def find_monthly_savings(amount, years): # used to divide the amount by years
  return amount / years

def amount(number): 
  if number < 0:
    return None

def years (months):
  if years < 0:
    return None


find_monthly_savings(amount = 360, years = 1)  #calling upon the dms function
```

Comment: do you really want to use multiple functions? you can simply check if your parameters are <0 in the find_monthly_savings function

Comment: I thought the equation required me to but afterwards it wast necessary I guess I was over-complicating the whole question, but it worked when I took out the other two statements and just used them as arguments in the fms function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def find_monthly_savings(amount, years): # used to divide amount by years
  if amount < 0:
      return None
  if years <= 0:
      return None
  return amount / years
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you, I just had to define years as years = years * 12 (I thought it would be the / but it worked) thank you!

Comment: Please select it as the correct answer if it solved your issue.